# Smooth transition between two Forms in VCL

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I have been playing around for few hours with this but I cannot make it work. I have an application made of two Forms, and I want to switch from one form to another. I want this switch to be "smooth" (ie blending effect).

I came up with this solution which works partially : using the AnimateWindow function in the ShowForm() method. This works fine when I switch from Form1 to Form2. But switching back to Form1 does not work. Form1 is painted "behind" Form2 and when Form2 hides, the transition is already done.

Below is the very simple code for Form1:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "main_form.h"
#include "child_form.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Form2 -> Show();
    Form1 -> Hide();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    const int speed = 1000;
    AnimateWindow(Handle, speed, AW_BLEND);
}
```

and here the code for Form2:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "child_form.h"
#include "main_form.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Form1 -> Show();
    Form2 -> Hide();

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    const int speed = 1000;
    AnimateWindow(Handle, speed, AW_BLEND);
}
```

I tried to invert the `Form1->Show()`and `Form2->Hide()`statements in the code for Form2, to force hiding Form2 before painting Form1, but it does not work either: Form2 is hidden, then nothing is shown during animation time, and then Form1 is displayed all of a sudden.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: In help of my version (XE7) it is said, not to use `TAnimateWindowProc()` directly. But in any case, the forms have a property `AlphaBlend` which enables/disables alphablending of forms, and an accompanying `AlphaBlendValue`. Increasing one forms value (0..255) in a loop, while decreasing another forms value (255..0) gives you the effect you are looking for. Both forms must have `Visible = True`.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks for the reply. I actually tried this solution before posting this and it does not work either. Actually it works once. The first time each form is created this works, and then the form is displayed directly, without any blending. I'll try editing the initial question with a sample code of this solution tomorrow. But still, it's really frustrating not to be able to control which form is in front of the other.

Comment: In my test I changed both forms `AlphaBlendValue` in a loop, and the problem you describe is not so apparent. But it has the effect that since both forms are partly transparent during the transition, whatever is behind shows through briefly. I understand that you want to avoid that. The problem that you raise in your question is due to the fact that **one of the forms is the main form**. If you can rearrange so that the forms you want to swap smoothly are "not-main-forms", then you can bring to front, before the loop, whichever form is to become visible.

Comment: Indeed the main problem is the fact that one of the form is the main form. I tried creating a blank 3rd form as the main one, with a black background, that partially solves this. I will post this as an answer for lack of a better solution for the moment. Can you post your code with the use of AlphaBlendValue as an answer to the question too? So I can check the difference with mine?

Answer (score 1):

As you requested, here's my take on the subject, but, as I'm shaky with C++Builder, in Delphi's pascal.

The problem you are describing (difference in behaviour depending on whether `Form1` or `Form2` is being brought to front) is due to `Form1` being the main form. The problem does not exist if neither form is a main form.

If one form is the main form, the problem is less visible if you use `AlphaBlendValue` to change both forms visibility simultaneously, that is, raise the value for the form to bring into view and decrease the value for the other one. As both forms are partly visible, their z order is not so apparent as if you change only one of the forms.

Begin with a project with two forms (TForm25 and TForm26 in my code).

```
TForm25
  property AlphaBlend = True
  property AlphaBlendValue = 255
  property Visible = True

TForm26
  property AlphaBlend = True
  property AlphaBlendValue = 0
  property Visible = True
```

Add following code somewhere where both forms has access to it.

```
procedure FadeOutIn(FOut, FIn: TForm);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  FIn.BringToFront;
  for i := 1 to 255 do
  begin
    FOut.AlphaBlendValue := 255-i;
    FIn.AlphaBlendValue := i;
    sleep(1); // use 20 for a really slow transition, just to demonstrate
              // or remove if not needed
  end;
end;
```

In my test both forms are autocreated, and `Visible = True` for both, but `Form26` is not visible since its `AlphaBlendValue = 0`. Each form has a button to call `FadeOutIn()` to fade out (hide) it self and fade in (show) the other form.

```
procedure TForm25.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FadeOutIn(Form25, Form26);
end;

procedure TForm26.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FadeOutIn(Form26, Form25);
end;
```

A caveat:
- As both forms are semi transparent simultaneously, whatever lies behind will also show through during the transition.

Comment: This works fine, but only if one of the forms is not the main form. If one of the form is the main one, there I still a strange effect I don't get. I can switch back and forth one time between forms, and then clicking again on Form1 shows briefly Form2 (without blending) and reverts back directly to Form1... By adding an extra blank Form as the main one, then it works perfectly, even with more than 2 windows.

Answer (score 0):

Following @TomBrunberg 's advice, here is a possible solution. The main problem here is that one of the Form is a MainForm which stays always behind the other. To circumvent this, a 3rd blank Form can be created and declared as the main one. This Form `Visible`property is set to `False`. The code for this 3rd Form is the following:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "background.h"
#include "main_form.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm3 *Form3;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm3::TForm3(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm3::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
     Form1->Show();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the code in the two other Form is modified so that the `Hide()` method is called before the `Show()` one as shown below.
Form1:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "main_form.h"
#include "child_form.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Form1 -> Visible = false;
    Form2 -> Visible = true;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    int const sleep = 500;
    AnimateWindow(Handle, sleep, AW_BLEND);
}
```

and Form 2

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "child_form.h"
#include "main_form.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Form2 -> Visible = false;
    Form1 -> Visible = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm2::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    int const sleep = 500;
    AnimateWindow(Handle, sleep, AW_BLEND);
}
```

This only partially works : at first launch, Form1 is displayed, without transition effect but it is not very important. But when Form2 is called for the first time, the transition effect does not work either and the blank Form3 is visible during the length of the transition effect. After this, it works and both Forms can be displayed with transition effects.

Comment: I don't understand why `Form3` would become visible suddenly. Do you call up `Form2` from `Form1` (as I would expect you to)  or ….?

Comment: Yes I do. I edited the answer to add the code for Forms 1 and 2.